# Linking problem with FreeMagic & GraphicsMagic

Tags: c, linux, graphics, 64-bit, linker

Whenever I link in either FreeMagic & GraphicsMagic, i get a SIGABRT as soon as main starts, possibly even before.  Any ideas?

It is not sufficient to just add the link flags, but for instance adding the call to FreeImage_Initialise(FALSE); somewhere in main() makes the program die in a SIGABRT.

Stacktrace from where it crashes:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6c47a75 in *__GI_raise (sig=<value optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff6c4b5c0 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x00007ffff73f41d1 in MHD_start_daemon_va () from /usr/lib/libmicrohttpd.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff73f481f in MHD_start_daemon () from /usr/lib/libmicrohttpd.so.5
#4  0x00000000004036f2 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffec98) at pasar.c:769
```

It always happen whenever I try to call MDH_start_daemon().

The same thing also happened when I link in another, unrelated as far as I know, image library, AfterImage.

Adding -pthread to LDFLAGS and CFLAGS makes no difference.

Comment: Run your program under GDB. GDB will stop when your program gets SIGABRT. At that point, execute 'where' command, which will give you crash stack trace. Modify your question to include that stack trace -- it is essential for answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I added -fPIC to CFLAGS and what-do-you-know, it works. Very interesting. If someone could explain why that is, would be very nice. You will then get my accept.

If no other answer appears shortly, I will accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code for [MHD_start_daemon_va()](https://gnunet.org/svn/libmicrohttpd/src/daemon/daemon.c), it appears that it will call `abort()` (via `mhd_panic`) IFF `pthread_mutex_lock()` fails.

Does relinking your program with `gcc -pthread ...` help?

Comment: Interesting, but no. No difference.